# When MongoDb increment integer value to NaN?

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple update query for incrementing an integer value in mongodb.

```
db.data.update({},{$inc: { x: y } })
```

This is an update command where i am incrementing the value of x by y.
Suppose I have only one document in the collection. Here x is an integer having value 10 in the document. For what value of y the value of x will become NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `y` = `NaN`:

```js
var x = 10;
var y = NaN;
console.log(x + y);
```

The same logic applies in MongoDB:

```
db.data.save({ x: 10 })
db.data.update({},{$inc: { x: NaN } })
```